# jquery loop animation delay adds up from the other elements

Tags: jquery, css, loops, animation

I have a gallery with images that i want to loop the animation delay for each image. my problem is that I have tabs on the same page with different galleries and i want the loop to start over for each gallery because now when you click on another tab the delay adds up from the other galleries and its not working correctly.

Html

```
 <div class="tab-content">
 <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
 <div class="gallery-canvas">
 <a rel="gallery-1" href="" >
 <img src="" alt="">
 </a>
 <a rel="gallery-1" href="" >
 <img src="" alt="">
 </a>
 <a rel="gallery-1" href="" >
 <img src="" alt="">
 </a>
 <a rel="gallery-1" href="" >
 <img src="" alt="">
 </a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="tab2" class="tab">
 <div class="gallery-canvas">
 <a rel="gallery-2" href="" >
 <img src="" alt="">
 </a>
 <a rel="gallery-2" href="" >
 <img src="" alt="">
 </a>
 <a rel="gallery-2" href="" >
 <img src="" alt="">
 </a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

jquery

```
      $(".gallery-canvas>a").each(function(index){
          $(this).css({
               'animation-delay' : 0.1*(1+index) + 's'
          });
    });
```

what i need is for every gallery canvas the loop to start over and not add up the delay from the before gallery canvas elements

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You just need to start your loop over for each `.gallery-canvas`.
You do that by nesting a separate loop for each `a` inside the loop for each `.gallery-canvas`:

```
$(".gallery-canvas").each(function() {
  $(this).children("a").each(function(i) {
    $(this).css({"animation-delay": (1+i)/10+"s"});
  });
});
```

- Note that I changed `0.1*(1+index)` to `(1+index)/10`.
  This is because multiplying by a fracture can give 'off' results, in your case I got values like `0.30000000000000004` and `0.6000000000000001`.

See the **code snippet** below for a demonstration:

```js
$(".gallery-canvas").each(function() {
  $(this).children("a").each(function(i) {
    $(this).css("animation-delay",(i+1)/10+"s");
    console.log($(this).attr("rel")+" - "+i+": "+ (i+1)/10);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
    <div class="gallery-canvas">
      <a rel="gallery-1" href="" ><img src="" alt=""></a>
      <a rel="gallery-1" href="" ><img src="" alt=""></a>
      <a rel="gallery-1" href="" ><img src="" alt=""></a>
      <a rel="gallery-1" href="" ><img src="" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <div class="gallery-canvas">
      <a rel="gallery-2" href="" ><img src="" alt=""></a>
      <a rel="gallery-2" href="" ><img src="" alt=""></a>
      <a rel="gallery-2" href="" ><img src="" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6ysw9ycq/1/*

Comment: @AnimalKingdom am I missing something, not the answer you were looking for?